# Updating "web.xml" when transitioning from Java Servlet 4 to Jakarta Servlet 5

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, web.xml

I am transitioning a simple Servlet from using Java Servlet 4 to [Jakarta Servlet 5](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/).

I noticed my `web.xml` file has references to the 4 spec.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns = "http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation = "http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version = "4.0">
</web-app>
```

- What does that fragment do anyways?
- How should I change those values to be appropriate the Jakarta Servlet 5?

I expect those `javaee` & `4` values should change.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Example from Tomcat

Here is what I am using in my *web.xml* file.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app
        xmlns = "https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
        xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation = "https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_5_0.xsd"
        version = "5.0"
        metadata-complete = "false"
>
    <display-name> Welcome to Tomcat</display-name>
    <description> Welcome to Tomcat</description>
</web-app>
```

This example is based on the *web.xml* file found within the `ROOT` web app bundled with Tomcat 10.0.x. Read section [*8.1 Annotations and Pluggability*](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/jakarta-servlet-spec-5.0.html#_Annotations_and_pluggability) of the [Jakarta Servlet 5 spec](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/) to decide whether you want `metadata-complete` set to `true` or `false`.

## Example in Servlet spec

See also an example of a deployment descriptor (web.xml) in section [*14.4.1. A Basic Example*](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/jakarta-servlet-spec-5.0.html#a-basic-example) of the [Jakarta Servlet Specification, Version 5.0](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/), Copyright (c) 2019, 2020 Eclipse Foundation.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee
         web-app_5_0.xsd"
         version="5.0">

  <display-name>A Simple Application</display-name>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>Webmaster</param-name>
    <param-value>webmaster@example.com</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>catalog</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.CatalogServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>catalog</param-name>
      <param-value>Spring</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>catalog</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/catalog/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
  </session-config>

  <mime-mapping>
    <extension>pdf</extension>
    <mime-type>application/pdf</mime-type>
  </mime-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/404.html</location>
  </error-page>

</web-app>
```

Comment: This web.xml was in the ROOT web app  in Tomcat 10.  See https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.0-doc/index.html

Comment: Well, never mind. I just downloaded Tomcat 10.0.18. There I found basically the same text you posted. Except for one important difference: `metadata-complete = "true"` while you have `false`. I edited your Answer to include more info. Thanks for your Answer, and the suggest to look at the bundled web apps.

Comment: @Basil  thank you for professionalism and completing the information. I use annotations.  So, I used the false value.

Comment: In Netbeans 13, when I do a "find usages", I get a warning message: "Potential changes cannot be propagated to web.xml because web application version is unsupported. Upgrade web.xml to version 2.4 or newer or use a previous version of NetBeans IDE." This is despite having updated the `web.xml` `web-app` element to version 5.0 as you have done. Using Tomcat10.0.21. Any ideas what it's complaining about?

Comment: @rickz your example does not validate for me unless I provided a full URL to the XSD file: `xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_5_0.xsd"`

Comment: Isn't that the same as the value given in the Tomcat example?

Comment: Likewise with 6.0. Doesn't validate: `xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee web-app_6_0.xsd"`.
Does: `xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_6_0.xsd"`.