# Javax is missing in Tomcat 10

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, soap, apache-axis

I have created very basic SOAP server with Java in my Eclipse and trying to run on Tomcat 10 with Axis2. Got exception:

```
...
INFO: Marking servlet [AdminServlet] as unavailable
Feb 01, 2023 6:41:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet [AdminServlet] in web application [/SOAPExample_Axis2] threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1437)
..
```

I suppose Tomcat need javax library. What is the best place to download this library I where I should place it in Tomcat?

Comment: Just use tomcat 9. Or use `jakarta.servlet.*` on tomcat 10.

Comment: See this Tomcat 10 [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/migration-10.html#Specification_APIs): "_There is a significant breaking change between Tomcat 9.0.x and Tomcat 10.0.x. The Java package used by the specification APIs has changed from javax... to jakarta...._". Simple example: You now need to refer to [`jakarta-servlet`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.servlet/jakarta.servlet-api) instead of [`javax-servlet`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api/4.0.1) in your `import` statements. I expect the same applies to other packages you may be using.

Comment: Also: [Updating "web.xml" when transitioning from Java Servlet 4 to Jakarta Servlet 5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71544097/12567365)

Comment: [*Transition from Java EE to Jakarta EE*](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/transition-from-java-ee-to-jakarta-ee) by Arjan Tijms, in Java Magazine, 2020-02.

Comment: [*Tomcat — Which version?*](https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html)